# Menu Bar Extra not opening on left click

Tags: swift, menubar, nsmenu

I have an app that shows a custom view on the menu bar of macOS. When the custom view is clicked, I want to show a context menu (NSMenu).

My code looks like this:

```
private let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system().statusItem(withLength: NSVariableStatusItemLength)
private var timer: Timer?
private var view: MenuView!
private var menu: NSMenu!
private let popover = NSPopover()
private var popoverController: PopoverViewController?

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
{
    self.view = createView()
    self.statusItem.view = self.view

    self.menu = NSMenu()
    self.menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: nil, keyEquivalent: ""))
    self.statusItem.menu = self.menu

    self.statusItem.menu = menu
}
```

However, when I click the view, the menu isn't shown like I would expect (well, it isn't shown at all).
When I don't use my custom view and only set up an image, the context menu opens when I click it.
How can I show the menu when using a custom view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a custom view you are responsible to handle all events, drawing and the highlighting.

In the `init(frame:`) method of the view pass the `NSStatusBar` instance. Assign the menu to the view rather than to `statusItem`.

At least you have to override `mouseDown`

```
override func mouseDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
    statusItem.popUpMenu(menu!)
    needsDisplay = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for the hint, I went with a slightly different approach. I still assigned the menu to the status item. When the view was clicked a notification is sent and then processed in the AppDelegate. Here the popUpMenu function is called. Thank you.

Comment: You are discouraged from sending notifications to `Appdelegate` because the instance is directly accessible from everywhere (`NSApp.delegate`). Use notifications only if there are multiple receivers or the views / controllers are not related to each other. Further I would recommend to keep the logic regarding the view always **in** the view.

Comment: Ok, I will change it then, thank you again. Didn't know about the NSApp.delegate access.